# Why do I need an infinite loop in STM32 programming?

Tags: c, arm, microcontroller, stm32, cortex-m

I'm programing a STM32F4 in C (gcc), it's a ARM Cortex M4, I see all examples finish their main() function with an infinite loop, even when the rest of the program will be executed from interruptions. If I try to remove the loop from my program, the interruptions stop being fired too.

Why can't I just remove this loop and exit the main thread?

here is the assembly (I guess it's thumb, but I can't read that, even with the doc):

```
LoopFillZerobss:
ldr  r3, = _ebss
cmp  r2, r3
bcc  FillZerobss

/* Call the clock system intitialization function.*/
bl  SystemInit 
/* Call the application's entry point.*/
bl  main
bx  lr    
.size  Reset_Handler, .-Reset_Handler
```

Comment: What do you expect the processor to do when you return from `main`?

Comment: @CarlNorum you should make that an answer.

Comment: @CarlNorum nothing, that's the point. Doing nothing between interruptions.

Comment: Well, that's what the infinite loop is, right?

Comment: it's spinning PC, eating clock etc. far from nothing.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that part, but does it not have a wait-for-interrupt instruction or something you could put in the loop, then?  Returning from `main` doesn't mean code stops executing, it means you're passing control back to *some other code*.

Comment: A quick google search turns up that this part is an ARM Cortex-M4. So it definitely has  a `WFI` instruction.  Use that if you want to enter a low power state in the idle loop: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABHHGEB.html

Comment: I added the assembly to my question, but to tell the truth I don't understand the doc for 'bx'. I really though my question was generic, it looks like the rabbit hole is deeper.

Comment: `bx` is the 'branch and exchange' instruction.  In this case, it's equivalent to the `return` statement in a C program.  So that means this code is trying to return to some other code.  If there *is* no calling code, the link register (`lr`) is probably garbage, and executing it causes a crash/exception.

Comment: As `bl main` will put `PC+4` in the *link register*, your following `bx lr` is an infinite loop; whether intentional or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the setup code that runs before `main` in your project.  It might be some slim assembly code or something more complicated, but in general it's pretty close to the bare minimum amount of processor setup required to initialize a stack and get the C runtime going.

If you were return from `main`, what is your processor supposed to do?  Reset?  Hang? There's no one good answer, so you'll have to look at the runtime support code being linked with your program to see what its designers decided. In your case, it sounds like they didn't make any allowances for `main` to return, so the processor just crashes/takes an exception and your program stops working.

Edit:  It seems like what you're actually looking for is a way to enter a low power state during the idle loop.  That's certainly possible - since your processor is an ARM Cortex-M4, there's a simple instruction to do just that:

```
while (1)
{
    asm("wfi");
}
```

If you're using CMSIS (and it looks like you are, given your use of `SystemInit`), the assembly is probably already done for you:

```
while(1)
{
   __WFI();
}
```

More details at [this link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0553a/BABHHGEB.html).

Comment: thank you very much, I'll take that as an answer, also this infinite loop is intellectually unsatisfying, you answered a lot about it.

Comment: Hopefully `WFI` does what you want. There are often some processor specific memory-mapped registers that control the specific behaviour that takes place when that instruction is executed.  Read your processor docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you are not running on an operating system.  main() is just a function like any other, it returns from where it was called.  With a bare metal system like this though that is not an operating system.  So if your software is all interrupt driven and main() is simply for setup, then you need to keep the processor in a controlled state either in an infinite loop or in a low power mode.  you can do that at the end of main() or whatever your setup function is called, or the assembly that calls main:

```
bl main
b . ;@ an infinite loop
```

or if you want wfi in there:

```
bl main
xyz:
wfi
b xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you haven't defined a interrupt handler which your program need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).