# When program finishes final line, it will set register r0 to 0

Tags: assembly, arm

I have code at the end of my program that is as follows:

```
        ldrb r2, [r1, #12] 
        sub r2, r2, #48
        cmp r2, r7 
        beq Check
        sub r0, r0, #1
Check   add r0, #1

END
```

If cmp r2, r7 decides r2 & r7 are equal, the program jumps to Check as should be expected. What is weird however is that after r1 has #1 added, it is then set to 0. The debugger shows the following in Disassembly:

```
0x00000088 E1A00000 NOP
that above line has a green icon to the left.
0x0000008C 30313338 EORCCS R3,R1,R8,LSR R3
0x00000090 30303135 EORCCS R3,R0,R5,LSR R1
0x00000094 30373338 EORCCS R3,R7,R8,LSR R3
the above three lines has an orange icon to the left.
0x00000098 0000008C ANDEQ R0,R0,R12,LSL #1
the above line has a light blue icon to the left.
```

How can I stop this from happening? (Running ARM7 (Big Endian))

Comment: That's not the disassembly of the above code, you must be looking at the wrong place.

Comment: It is in the window labeled "Disassembly".

Comment: So, you run off the end of the code, start executing whatever rubbish is in that part of memory, and _unexpected things happen_? Inconceivable!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need an infinite loop in STM32 programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255056/why-do-i-need-an-infinite-loop-in-stm32-programming)

Comment: @Notlikethat Do you think a teacher would take marks off for not 'cleaning' that rubbish? I am new to assembly, so I actually didn't realize that behaviour.

Comment: Absolutely not! Generally, the stuff immediately after the code is still other vital parts of your program - literal pools for constants, strings, etc. It's just not _instructions_. Processors are simple, stupid creatures that simply carry on fetching what's at the next address and trying to execute it - you can't _stop_ them doing that (well, not in normal operation at least) so if there's no operating system to return to, and really nothing left to do then it's safest just to leave them running in circles, as per the question I linked.

Comment: Indeed, it's more of a (un)fortunate coincidence that this data - I'm guessing an array of ASCII digits and a variable containing the address of that array - can be interpreted as valid ARM instructions and executed without causing any exceptions ;)

Comment: (Time to let out that sigh of relief) Well today I learned something new, Thanks!